# Square-Cube and Kinetic Energy equations for relative numbers (mostly specific to personal project)

Tags: physics, science-fiction, mathematics

This is a somewhat long and arduous question, (and is likely to help me in particular far more than it will help anyone else, since it's quite specific to my own project) but I hope you'll bear with me. I'm in the middle of writing a hard-scifi novel, and within it are massive events and battles which I intend to reflect true physics in every respect (at least relative to certain invented in-universe values). I understand many of the physical principles I need to account for and calculate, but I simply lack the math skills to calculate some of them properly.

I have a few directly interrelated problems. ***1)*** is calculating the precise sizes and masses of various objects based on the Square Cube Law---in this case, railgun projectiles. In my novel there are 25 grades of a particular kind of railgun, each grade with its corresponding projectile:

**1 | 2 | 3| 4 | 5** *(1m/1.0 tons)* **| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10** *(2m/8.0 tons)* **| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20** *(4m/64.0 tons)*   **| 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | *[40]*** *(8m/512 tons)*

The materials, shape, and relative dimensions are identical from grade to grade. I already know that Grade-5 is 1m in diameter, with a mass of 1 ton (I simply invented that value, and used it to extrapolate the following values), Grade-10 is 2m/8tons, and Grade-20 is 4m/64tons. There is technically no Grade-40 in my novel, but as shown above, it would hypothetically be 8m/512tons. My largest grade, Gade-25, is 5m, but I haven't been able to figure out its exact tonnage. I'm sure the math is simple, but I'm ignorant of precisely what that math is, and how to accurately calculate the relative size differences of the odd in-between sizes that are not exactly double or half the size of another known value---which then leaves me unable to apply correctly modified Square-Cube values to them for tonnage.

***2)*** Which itself is the second part of the problem. Since the in between values are not exactly double or half of the known values, I also don't know how to calculate modified Square-Cube values to multiply/divide with for those sizes (can't multiply/divide by 8 for those). It was easy for me to calculate the known values---I simply gave Grade-5 the value of 1.0 tons, and since Grade-10 is twice that size, I multiplied by 8 to get 8.0 tons, then by 8 again to get 64.0 tons for Grade-20.

***3)*** With that being accomplished, the third related part of the problem is then calculating their kinetic energy (double the mass, kinetic energy is doubled---double the velocity, kinetic energy is quadrupled). Having now precisely calculated each projectile's mass, and assuming the same velocity for each, I need to apply the correct relative values---which I am currently unable to do for the same reasons as the above problems. To extrapolate the numbers for kinetic energy, I'll give Grade-25 a value of 1000.0 for kinetic energy, and all other grades will be proportionately less than that. Perhaps the same numbers that went into calculating the square-cube for each Grade will be used to calculate kinetic energy values for the same Grades?

Again, I know this is a long and arduous question, but if anyone could help me find the correct values for each Grade for both tonnage and kinetic energy, and show me the appropriate formulae for both (but also explain them so that a relative layperson like me can understand them, and perhaps then even be able to apply them to different situations), it would truly be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you not understand how to cube a number?

Comment: You want you Grade to be directly proportional to Diameter at grades 5, 10, 20 and 40, but want different proportion in-between? Can you try to draw a chart and tell us what do you think diameter/mass of, say, grade 8 should be?

Comment: Yes, all are directly proportional to those diameters. My (probably incorrect) previous guess was that Grade-8 would be just under 1 meter diameter at 4.8 tons, Grade-9 would be just under 2 meters at 6.4 tons, etc. I simply don't know if those are correct values (can't remember how I came to them), and don't know how to apply Square-Cube relative to the other known values. Since Grade-10 is twice the size of Grade-5, it's easy for me to get Grade-10's mass of 8.0t. But the higher the Grade, the more increments there are in between a doubled size, which complicates the math for me.

Comment: If you want to stick with 1 ton for grade 5, your formula is simple. m = N**3 / 125 (N**3 is a cube of grade).

Comment: Why don't you actually _calculate_ the mass of the projectile and its kinetic energy? You know, from scratch. A gun with a calibre of 10 cm will trow a ball of iron with a diameter of 10 cm, with a volume of 393 cm³; the density of iron being 7.87, that ball weighs about 3 kg (6.6 English pounds). Let's say that the gun has a barrel length of 1.5 meters and throws the ball with 400 m/s (about 25% faster than sound), giving it an energy of about 2.5 MJ. To get roughly the same muzzle velocity the length of the barrels will scale linearly with the calibre.

Comment: Alexander---so I cube Grade-9 (729), then divide by 125 for an answer of 5.832. Grade-8 would be 4.096. Is this correct? Would I need another similar equation for diameter?

Comment: Diameter is even simpler - d = N/5. But pay attention to AlexP's comment. Think about shape and density of your projectiles.

Comment: AlexP---Thanks for your help. I would love to be able to figure these things from scratch, as that would certainly yield the best results for my problems, but I don't seem to understand the math concepts thoroughly enough to do so properly. Your example is fairly clear to me, but it's easier when the numbers are already supplied by someone like you who is familiar with the concepts. If I input my own numbers, I couldn't be sure I was doing the math properly.

Comment: Do you do every calculation by hand or do you know some basic programming? You wouldn't have to worry about doing the math properly more than once if the computer is doing it. It would also be a lot faster. I do not know how much time you spend with such calculations when writing a novel, but learning e.g. python well enough from scratch for scripts dealing with such calculations takes about a week with ~1-3 hours a day of tutorials.

Comment: I do it by hand, and only to the best of my limited abilities. I don't know programming, but have been interested in learning. I just did a search on 'python'. Looks a little out of my league, but I'll look into it further. Thanks for that.

Comment: It looks scary at first, but it will get friendly pretty fast. If it's too scary and you are for example either a university student (they often get it for free from their university) or rich, you could also buy Mathematica or a similar program that comes with a nice graphical interface and buttons. I personally prefer something like python though. But just to be clear, that was a general hint since it sounded as if you were doing it by hand. You would still have to figure out the equations first in order to program them initially

Comment: If you have Excel, it's formula calculation probably going to be sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that you can use the '@<username>' syntax to notify one user per comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The size seems to be, for instance, **the diameter is (Grade/5) meters**.  The length would be (Grade/5) * length of grade 5 projectile.

2) This is pretty simple.  It's  **(Grade/ 5 ) ^ 3 tons**.  So, for instance, a gauge 1 railgun is ( 1/5) ^ 3 = 1/125th of a ton, or 0.008 tons.

2) It's a tad annoying that you switched the standard to Grade 25, but since KE = 1/3 m x V^2, and since only m is changing, you end up with, like mass, (Grade/25)^3 x 1000.0 .   If you wanted to base it off of Grade 5 instead, it would be **(Grade/5)^3 x 8.0 energy units**  (because we pull the 1/125 out from the cube function and apply it to the constant)

Comment: Tell me if I did this right. To calculate KE for Grade-24, I divided 24 by 25 (0.96). Cubed=0.84934656. Multiplied by 1000=849.34656. Is this correct?

Comment: It's correct, except I have 0.96^3 = 0.884736.  I'm not sure if you were cubing by hand, or entered it into a calculator incorrectly.  So, I have KE = 884.736

Comment: I used a windows calculator. Funny though, I keep getting 0.84934656. Good to know I got the principle correct though. Thanks.

Comment: @Sci-Hard That's odd. 0.96^3 should certainly not be anywhere near 0.85. Using three different calculators (the GNOME Calculator, Perl, and my trusty old handheld electronic "scientific" calculator which has nothing to do with my PC except that it shares a desk with it as I'm trying that...) I keep getting the answer 0.884736. You are probably doing something wrong somewhere if you keep getting 0.84934656.

Comment: @Sci-Hard 0.96^4 = 0.84934656,  You cannot just square a number twice, you have to use the cube button.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. As I said, I'm not entirely clear on all things math. :)

Comment: @Sci-Hard $x^4 = x^{2 \times 2} = x^2 \times x^2 = x \times x \times x \times x$ Remember that exponentiation is basically just a fancy way to write repeat multiplication: $x^y$ is $x$ multiplied by itself a total of $y$ times, with the special case that $x^0 = 1$ for any $x$ (this follows from applying the same rule in reverse, basically $x^y = \frac{x^{y+1}}{x}$ for any values of $x$ and $y$). Complex numbers with an imaginary portion do complicate this slightly, but I believe we don't need to go there... :-)